# Golang return file from fly

Tags: go, ini, go-echo

I have the ECHO framework which should return the file on request, and it's working well

```
func IniExport(c echo.Context) error{
    cfg := ini.Empty()
    if section, err := cfg.NewSection("test_section"); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Problems with generation of export file.")
    }
    if key, err := cfg.Section("test_section").NewKey("name", "value"); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Problems with generation of export file.")
    }
    cfg.SaveTo("export.ini")
    defer os.Remove("export.ini")
    return c.Attachment("export.ini", "export.ini")
}
```

But question, is it possible to not create physical file export.ini and after do not remove it? Possible to return content on the fly somehow?
Thanks

Comment: Yes of course if your cfg can write  itself to a io.Writer. As you did not explain what `ini` is we cannot help you there.

Comment: Ini is simple "gopkg.in/ini.v1" library

Comment: So just use https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ini.v1#File.WriteTo. Always read the full package doc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [Send Blob](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/response#send-attachment).

> Send Blob **Context#Blob(code int, contentType string, b []byte)** can be
> used to send an arbitrary data response with provided content type and
> status code.
>
> Example

```
func(c echo.Context) (err error) {
  data := []byte(`0306703,0035866,NO_ACTION,06/19/2006
      0086003,"0005866",UPDATED,06/19/2006`)
    return c.Blob(http.StatusOK, "text/csv", data)
}
```

You can use the [WriteTo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-ini/ini.v1#File.WriteTo) function to write the `cfg` content to the `io.Writer` first and then those contents can be used instead of `data`(in the previous code example. Also make sure to change the content type to `text/plain`)